# How to test `contenteditable` events with React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, contenteditable, react-testing-library, slatejs, testing-library

I am trying to write tests for one of our rich text components which was implemented with slate js editor in react js. So when writing tests, I am retrieveing the element div[contenteditable='true'], but not able to simulate events like change, blur, focus. The handlers attached to editor component are not getting called. I tried multiple combinations, but no luck. Can someone please help on this? Is it possible to simulate events for contenteditable element using testing library (contenteditable is implemented using slatejs)?

Comment: known issue for long
1. https://spectrum.chat/testing-library/general/possible-to-simulate-events-on-div-contenteditable-true~85c08fa4-3394-4c60-b5a2-81a6a9ee35e4
2. https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1670

Answer (score 4):

Like you've discovered, `contenteditable` isn't supported by JSDOM. React Testing Library (RTL) is built on top of JSDOM, so it's not possible to test the Slate editor properly with RTL until JSDOM implements support for `contenteditable`.

#### Use a browser automation library together with Testing Library

Your options are then to use a tool that creates a real browser context. Testing Library have integrations with many tools that do exactly that: [TestCafe](https://testing-library.com/docs/testcafe-testing-library/intro), [Cypress](https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro), [Nightwatch](https://testing-library.com/docs/nightwatch-testing-library/intro), [Puppeteer](https://testing-library.com/docs/pptr-testing-library/intro/).

*You can also use the above tools on their own, without Testing Library.*

I've solved this using Puppeteer, and there are two approaches:

1. Run a local server and tell Puppeteer to go to something like `localhost:3000`
2. Set the content directly with `page.setContent(htmlString)`

(1) is the most common, and you'll find many guides for this since it's a common approach for end-to-end testing ([google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=puppeteer+testing+library+react&oq=puppeteer+testing+library+react&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30i457.4497j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)).

(2) is a little trickier because you will have to transform and bundle your source for each test, and then inject it as HTML into the browser page. **I prefer this approach because the testing experience is much more similar to using RTL.** I've created a repository with an example of this setup with the Slate editor here: https://github.com/marcusstenbeck/puppeteer-react-testing-template/